# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have done the below things with xml based configuration, when I start migrate to java config I got this problem.It involves Jdbc connection with MS Access. I have jdbc config in property file and reading it from factory file.

Please help me  on this,

```
    **Web.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </context-param>


        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.jdbc.config</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>DispatcherConfiguration</servlet-name>
            <!-- dispatcher will map -servlet and look for dispatcher-servlet.xml file 
                inside WEB-INF -->
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <!-- No explicit configuration file reference here: everything is configured in the root container for simplicity -->                
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>com.jdbc.config</param-value>
            </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>DispatcherConfiguration</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>




    </web-app>




    **My Dispatcher Config java file**

    package org.jdbc.config;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;


    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan( basePackages= {
        "org.jdbc.controller",
        "org.jdbc.config",
        "org.jdbc.service",
        } )
    public class DispatcherConfiguration {


        @Bean
        public static DataSource getDataSource(){
            DriverManagerDataSource source = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            source.setDriverClassName(getConnectionFactory().getDriver());
            source.setUrl(getConnectionFactory().getDbURL());
            return source;
        }

        @Bean
        public static ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory(){
            return new ConnectionFactory();

        }
    }



    **Controller Class:**

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users")
    public class MainController {

        @Autowired
        private IUserDAO userDAO;

        //insert
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public Person create(@RequestBody Person person) {
            /* LOGGER.info("Creating new user {}", user); */
            userDAO.insertUser(person.getFirstName());
            return person;
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Person read(@PathVariable(value = "userId") int userId) {
            // LOGGER.info("Reading user with id {}", userId);
            Person person = userDAO.getUser(userId);
            Validate.isTrue(person != null, "Unable to find user with id: " + userId);
            return person;
        }

        //create table
        @RequestMapping(value="{/tName}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public void createTable (@PathVariable(value = "tName") String tName) {
            System.out.println("Coming inot the picture@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
            userDAO.createTable();

        }


    }
```

Comment: have you checked wether `<param-value>com.jdbc.config</param-value>` you have specified it correctly, because your package starts with `org.jdbc.config`. Please try using this inside `contextConfigLocation`

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed.Could not autowire field: private org.jdbc.service.IUserDAO org.jdbc.controller.MainController.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path

Comment: please post the code for `IUserDAO` also, how have you defined bean for it.

Comment: Problem was solved, it is not reading the property file which contains database configuration details, I just added that property file under resources folder, it was run successfully. Thanks